# Solidity ParserError: Expected identifier but got '('

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Keep getting an error  by  my constructor

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.9;

contract Confrence{
    address public organizer;
    mapping (address => uint) public registrantsPaid;
    uint public numRegisrants;
    uint public quota;
    
    //so you can log these events 
    event Deposit(address _from, uint _amount);
    event Refund(address _to, uint _amount);

     Confrence() public {//consturctor
        organizer = msg.sender;
        quota = 500;
        numRegistrants = 0; 
    
    }

}
```

Is it that I need to put parameters in the parenthesis?

Comment: Try insert *space*: `contract Confrence {`. But specifying the line where the error occurred would help a lot.

Comment: ohhh thanks this helped @MentatX